# VSCodeの拡張機能のLive Sass Compilerを使ってwatch sassを押してもCompilation Error Error: Stack Overflowと出てSCSSファイルをコンパイルができない

Tags: vscode, sass

VSCodeの拡張機能のLive Sass Compilerを使ってwatch sassを押してもCompilation Error Error: Stack Overflowと出てSCSSファイルをコンパイルができない

```
Compilation Error
Error: Stack Overflow
```

#### 試したこと:

VSCode の拡張機能を全部アンインストールした

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事がヒントになるかも。[Live Sass Compiler - @use causes compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66193156/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

SCSSファイルをコピして新しいフォルダに全く同じファイルを作ったらうまくいきました
たぶんコンパイルされたcssファイルをいじってしまったからだと思います